# When the Client application is manualy closed how to know it in server side, using C#

Tags: sockets, client-server

In a client server communcation, When the Client application is manualy closed how to know it in server side, using C#.

I have disconnect chances in two ways.
1. Manualy closing the client application
2. network cable is unpluging.

If any one have a solution please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You know that by two ways:

1. `recv`/`read` returns 0. That means that the client gracefully ended sending data. The connection might still be open but the client can no longer send data. You can now close the connection if you wish.
2. You get an error telling you that the connection was interrupted.

Comment: Socket.Receive/Socket.Send will returns number of bytes successfully read or write from/to the socket right? i am getting success for these functions even if the network cable is unplugged or the client get rebooted before calling send method.

Comment: Send does not return any number. It does not make sure that bytes were received. Make the other side reply to you with an acknowledgement to be sure that the bytes sent are received.; Btw, I told you by what means you can detect a disconnect. You can't detect it using send alone. Anything unclear?